# Jcrop onselect not working in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jcrop

I'm using Jcrop in a project I'm working on. For some reason, the function I have specified in Jcrop's OnSelect isn't firing.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   <script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery('#<%= img_up_photo.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
   onSelect: storeCoords,
   bgOpacity: .6,
   setSelect: [0, 0, 100, 100],
   aspectRatio: 1
   });
   });
    function storeCoords(c) {
        alert('hi');
        $('#<%= hdnx.ClientID %>').val(c.x);
        $('#<%= hdny.ClientID %>').val(c.y);
        $('#<%= hdnw.ClientID %>').val(c.w);
        $('#<%= hdnh.ClientID %>').val(c.h);

    };
    </script>
```

I'm placed this controls inside a UpdatePanel .

Comment: It was difficult to identify in jcrop for me , and diverted to use ImageProcessor to crop exactly